# Optional Parameters in xparse: \IfBooleanTF vs \IfNoValueTF

Tags: macros, xparse, optional-arguments

I tend to get `\IfBooleanTF` and `\IfNoValueTF` (and the other similar macros) mixed up and wondering which is the correct ones to use for the following optional parameters:
`s`,
`o`,
`d`,
`g`,
`k_` (and `k^`) and
`t_` (and `t^`).
From the documenation it seems that one should use:

- `\IfBooleanTF`: `s`, `t`
- `\IfNoValueTF`: `o`, `d`, `g`, `k`

### Questions:

1. Is the above list of macros to use correct?
2. What is the intention of distinguishing between `\IfBooleanTF` and `\IfNoValueTF`? Wouldn't it make sense to just have one macro that does both jobs? Or, is there a case where a distinction is required?  `t` and `k` using different macros is especially confusing to me.

My reason for asking is: If I can understand the logic behind this, perhaps I'll be able to remember to use the correct ones.

### Follow-up Question:

- [Xparse's new e-type argument (replacement for k-type argument)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345365/4301)

### References:

- `s`: [Defining starred versions of commands (* macro)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4386/4301)
- `o`: [xparse: Define new command with multiple optional parameters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33749/4301)
- `d`: [Combine todonotes with mdframed to highlight paragraphs and write notes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/210377/4301),
- `g`: [Is it possible to use {} as delimiter for an optional xparse argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/255762/4301)
- `k`: [Xparse k argument to parse options at end of environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319476/4301)
- `t`: [Xparse t argument type (underscore with optional parameter)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319304/4301)

Comment: With s or t you ask TeX to see whether or not a particular token follows, so it's a true or false situation; the token is never used as such.

Comment: You should add also `d` to the argument types that need `\IfNoValue(TF)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the above is correct.

The two cases are logically distinct as you are *passing different information*. The aim of `xparse` is to make this structural information clear.

For `\IfBoolean(TF)`, the argument is a *single token* which can only be one of two values: TRUE and FALSE. A value is *always* returned by the `t` (and `s`) argument types, and the test is there to see which it is. One may also reverse the logic returned here using `\ReverseBoolean`: the presence of the token does not have to map to logically TRUE.

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand \foo { >{ \ReverseBoolean } s }
   {
      \IfBooleanTF #1
        { Star not present }
        { Star present }
   }
```

On the other hand, argument types which grab 'some tokens' may not be present (so yield `\NoValue`), be present-but-empty or be present-and-non-empty. The logic that something is *present* cannot be reversed so `\IfNoValue` will always be true only if the optional argument was not given at all.

---

The `k`-type argument has recently been adjusted: you now want `e`-type. This one is somewhat specialised and the team have had quite a bit of discussion about the correct form here.

Comment: Could you sum up what has been the discussion around `k` (now `e`). I'm out of the loop, but I'm interested. No details, just in the broad sense.

Comment: I noticed that the `k` parameter is not mentioned in the 2016-11-21 version of the `xparse` documentation. Can I safely assume that its functionality will be left intact or will it evenatually be removed? Also, can you add to your answer at [Xparse t argument type (underscore with optional parameter)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319315/4301) to include an example of the `e` type option (not sure I fully understand it from the documentation).

Comment: @Manuel That would be a separate question I think

Comment: @PeterGrill As covered in the documentation, `e`-type is _experimental_: we have to have some way to test out ideas without committing to everything up-front. We are likely to retain some form of '`^`/`_`-like' input parsing, but the detail is more tricky. (Discussion of these ideas is the is best on LaTeX-L)

Comment: @JosephWright: Ok, but what is the plan for the `k` parameter. Is the plan to leave it as is, or should switch to using the `t` paramameter in my code?

Comment: @Manuel: Yes that would be a great new question. If you do post it, please add some comment regarding the future of the `k` parameter. If you don't want to do it, let me know and I will post it.

Comment: @PeterGrill Feel free to post.

Comment: @Manuel: See [Xparse's new e-type argument (replacement for k-type argument)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/345365/4301)